# List input and list created different

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, input

When I create list as

```
a=[5,6,8,7]; print(a)
```

it shows output as

```
[5, 6, 8, 7]
```

and when take input as

```
b=list(input());print(b)
```

it shows output as

```
['5', '6', '7', '8']
```

why and what is difference in that. I can add 5 and 6  as 11 but in second adding 5 and 6 is 56 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `input()` returns a string and `+` is thus doing string concatenation. From the `input()` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input):

> The function then reads a line from input, converts it to a string
>   (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that.

Comment: @briangrey, consider marking an answer as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

`input()` returns a *string*, `list(input())` extracts its individual characters and puts them in a list. Adding individual characters, which are strings of one character, produces a new string:

```
'5' + '6' == '56'
5 + 6 == 11
```

To convert a list of strings to a list of integers, use `map`:

```
integers = list(map(int, input()))
```

Comment: "Use map"...or use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions): `integers = [int(c) for c in input()]`